# Audit who calls binary

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, audit

Need to get parent process and/or user of curl that, I know, starts from time to time on some server.

Audit is used by others, so I can not trivialy configure it. Is there any other tools?

Comment: Why not `audit`? You can just add one more rule. Something like can do the work: `auditctl -a always,exit -F exe=/bin/curl -F arch=b64 -S execve -k curl_exec`